# SPSiteDataQuery not displaying some of the ListItem data

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I'm trying to create a web part that reads all Tasks lists in a given web (and it's sub webs) bringing some information that i'll have displayed on a GridView. I need to bring only the first/parent item of each list to display the task's Title, Start date, Due date, Status, who's it assigned to and the % of completion.

To do that, I've created a GridView on my ascx file

```
<asp:GridView ID="gridTasks" AutoGenerateColumns="true" runat="server" ShowHeader="true" />
```

And for the data, i'm using the SPSiteDataQuery object to retrieve the data i need

```
SPSiteDataQuery query = new SPSiteDataQuery();
query.Webs = "<Webs Scope='Recursive'>";
query.Lists = "<Lists ServerTemplate='171'/>";
query.ViewFields = "<FieldRef Name='Title' Type='Text'/>";
query.ViewFields += "<FieldRef Name='StartDate' />";
query.ViewFields += "<FieldRef Name='DueDate' />";
query.ViewFields += "<FieldRef Name='Status' />";
query.ViewFields += "<FieldRef Name='AssignedTo' Type='User' Nullable='TRUE' />";
query.ViewFields += "<FieldRef Name='PercentComplete' Type='Number' Nullable='TRUE' />";
// ParentID is here just for testing purpose
query.ViewFields += "<FieldRef Name='ParentID' Type='Number' Nullable='TRUE' />";
query.Query = "<Where><IsNull><FieldRef Name='ParentID' /></IsNull></Where>";
query.Query = "<OrderBy><FieldRef Name='Title' Ascending='True'/></OrderBy>";

gridTasks.DataSource = web.GetSiteData(query);
gridTasks.DataBind();
```

When i run this code, it brings me data, but with some issues, the  statement is being completely ignored, it's bringing ALL items in the Tasks list. Checking the grid view after it's filled with the data, i saw that the columns 'AssignedTo' and 'ParentID' are empty, it's not bringing any information for those two columns.

That is (for me) very strange, because if i run the following code and debug it, i get my two string variables filled with the correct information.

```
foreach (SPListItem item in web.Lists["Tasks"].Items)
{
     String who = Convert.ToString(item["AssignedTo"]);
     String parent = Convert.ToString(item["ParentID"]);
}
```

Is this a common issue? Is there anything different i need to do to with my SPSiteDataQuery or is there any other way to achieve what i need to do?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly,

As pointed on the article http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2703054, the SPSiteDataQuery doesn't support multi-valued fields, which is the case of the AssignedTo field, it'll always bring null for those fields.

Answer (score 2):

```
query.Query = "<Where><IsNull><FieldRef Name='ParentID' /></IsNull></Where>";
query.Query = "<OrderBy><FieldRef Name='Title' Ascending='True'/></OrderBy>";
```

There's your problem, you're overwriting the query.Query bit with the second line.  The Query property's contents needs to be wrapped in a `<Query />` node, too.

Comment: And since you only retrieve list items where ParentID is null, there is no strike that this field is just that in all of the items also after this error is corrected.

Comment: Oh dear... Thanks for pointing that out James. Got the code filter just for the item without a ParentID, but the AssignedTo column still being null, I've changed the type of the field to UserMulti but that too didn't bring any data.